# SPILL! Error when pasting XLOOKUP formula to other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm new to using XLOOKUP, so this might be a dumb question, but I have created the following formula to pull data meeting 2 criteria from a separate Excel file.  It works as expected where the formula is originally created, but when I attempt to paste it to other cells, I'm getting a SPILL error I don't understand.  Thanks for any help.  Here's the formula:

```
'=XLOOKUP(A3&$B$1,'[HeatMap Fuel Automated 2023.xlsx]Lines'!$F:$F&'[HeatMap Fuel Automated 2023.xlsx]Lines'!$C:$C,'[HeatMap Fuel Automated 2023.xlsx]Lines'!$G:$G,'[HeatMap Fuel Automated 2023.xlsx]Lines'!$E:$E)'
```

So the idea is to iterate the same formula over A4, A5, A6, etc. referencing the same array in the other spreadsheet, with B1 remaining a constant.  But whether I do it by copy-paste or do it by hand-typing the formula, this breaks with a SPILL error.

Thank you for any guidance.

Edited to add sample of data as requested by commenters. Note that the cell reference to B2 is intended to point to a manually entered number corresponding to the week being analyzed. So if I entered "1" the search would key on week 1 as a condition.  Column A in the formula corresponds to a column with team names in it, checking whether it matches the "awayTeam" or not.  If so, the formula is supposed to put the score for the away team into a "team score" column, and not, it is supposed to put the score for the visiting team in the "team score" column. Thank you for your assistance.

| id | season | week | homeTeam | homeScore | awayTeam | awayScore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 401540213 | 2023 | 1 | McNeese | 34 | Tarleton State | 52 |
| 401540199 | 2023 | 1 | Mercer | 17 | North Alabama | 7 |
| 401540078 | 2023 | 1 | Lehigh | 10 | Villanova | 38 |
| 401540311 | 2023 | 1 | Campbell | 24 | William & Mary | 34 |
| 401520158 | 2023 | 1 | Jackson | 49 | East Tenn | 3 |

Editing a second time as requested to explain the desired result.

The logic I am trying to build (which, again, works in the first row but then gives the SPILL error in any others) is this:

*For games that occurred in week B2, check whether the team name in Column A appears in the "awayTeam" column (column F).  If yes, then copy the value in the "awayScore" column (column G) for that row into the cell in the new sheet (which is in a column titled "Team Score"). If no, then copy the value in the "homeScore" column (column E) from that row into the cell on the new sheet.  The I use the same formula with the variables switched to populate a second column called "Opponent Score."  So the result should look like this, for the sample data provided (assume the value entered into B2 is 1):

| Team Analyzed | Team Score | Opponent Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| McNeese | 34 | 52 |
| Tarleton State | 52 | 34 |
| Mercer | 17 | 7 |
| North Alabama | 7 | 17 |

. . . and so on.

Comment: May be I am wrong, but a wild guess, you are getting the spill error because of this parameter **[if_not_found]** --> `'[HeatMap Fuel Automated 2023.xlsx]Lines'!$E:$E` please try to evaluate the formula and see whether the  **lookup_value** is really can find any value `A3&$B$1` from `[HeatMap Fuel Automated 2023.xlsx]Lines'!$F:$F&'[HeatMap Fuel Automated 2023.xlsx]Lines'!$C:$C` . May be I am wrong its an assumption since i cant see the data sample.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya -- added data as requested.

Comment: @BlindSpots  - added data as requested.

Comment: _Re: If so, the formula is supposed to put the score for the home team into a "team score" column, and not, it is supposed to put the score for the visiting team in the "team score" column._ So if the formula doesnt finds the home team then it would certainly return a `SPILL` array of the visiting team score, and if you are using the formulas within a `Structured References` then it would show you a `#SPILL!` error. If I am not wrong and mistaken. If there is something please clarify it will help both of us.

Comment: @BlindSpots - thanks. I've spelled out and illustrated the desired result as requested.  Let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya -- added clarification as requested.  Let me know if I can add more.

Comment: @janalytics its fine, just saw BlindSpots has given you a solution, which should work for you!

Comment: [Updated the formula](https://superuser.com/a/1815706/) based on new info.  You need to copy it down the column.  I will update it to an array formula that spills down later when I have time.  Please invest more time next time to save our time.

Comment: [Converted the formula to an Array Formula fixed typo in results table](https://superuser.com/a/1815706/)  Let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Array Formula in `C2`

```
=LET(
   rng,'[HeatMap Fuel Automated 2023.xlsx]Lines'!C:G, 
   lookup,A2:A100, wk,B2, names,TOCOL(lookup,1),
   arr, FILTER(rng,(INDEX(rng,,1)=wk)),
   IF(INDEX(arr,,2)=names,
     CHOOSECOLS(arr,3,5),
     CHOOSECOLS(arr,5,3)))
```

#### Sample Data

`[HeatMap Fuel Automated 2023.xlsx]Lines`

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **id** | **season** | **week** | **homeTeam** | **homeScore** | **awayTeam** | **awayScore** |
| **2** | 401540213 | 2023 | 1 | McNeese | 34 | Tarleton State | 52 |
| **3** | 401540199 | 2023 | 1 | Mercer | 17 | North Alabama | 7 |
| **4** | 401540078 | 2023 | 1 | Lehigh | 10 | Villanova | 38 |
| **5** | 401540311 | 2023 | 1 | Campbell | 24 | William & Mary | 34 |
| **6** | 401520158 | 2023 | 1 | Jackson | 49 | East Tenn | 3 |

### Sample Results

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Names** | **Week** | **Team Score** | **Opponent Score** |
| **2** | McNeese | 1 | 34 | 52 |
| **3** | Mercer |  | 17 | 7 |
| **4** | North Alabama |  | 38 | 10 |
| **5** | William & Mary |  | 34 | 24 |
| **6** | East Tenn |  | 3 | 49 |